# Meteor Spiderable package is not working with Meteor 0.9.0

Tags: javascript, meteor, phantomjs

I have followed all instructions for installing the phantomjs and spiderable package (working from this video: https://www.eventedmind.com/feed/meteor-the-spiderable-package) and I can see the  tag appear okay.  However on both localhost and the deployed application, the source shows only the typical meteor javascript files.  It does not convert the script to proper html.

I have checked that phantomjs is installed both locally and on the production server.  I have checked that the spiderable package is listed in my meteor app.  If I add ?_escaped_fragment_= to the URL I can see the html source is correct.  I am running Meteor 0.9.0 if that makes any difference.

Please visit the production site to see : http://www.theyfind.me/

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Everything looks OK when I visit http://www.theyfind.me/?_escaped_fragment_=, so you are fine. Web spiders will crawl your site using the AJAX friendly URL, not the default one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have **Meteor 0.9 or later** you must install the package **without meteorite**. Now, you must to install the package with Meteor add, for example in your case:

**Spiderable**

http://atmospherejs.com/gadicohen/spiderable-remote

```
meteor add gadicohen:spiderable-remote
```

**Phanthom**

http://atmospherejs.com/gadicohen/phantomjs

```
meteor add gadicohen:phantomjs
```